# Get the property from a private variable

Tags: java

I created 2 methods. `Method1` assigns value to a variable via `setter`, `method2` gets the value of the variable via a `getter`.

However, when I call `method2` the program returns `null` or `null`. Only private variables can be used, do not use `public` or `static`.

Is there any solution or code example for me? Sorry, I'm a newbie. Thanks very much!

```
class Info {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Info() {

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.method1();
        test.method2();
    }

    public void method1() {
        Info a = new Info();
        a.setName("John");
        a.setAge(21);
    }

    public void method2() {
        Info a = new Info();
        //I want to print Name and Age values from class Info after method1 set value
        System.out.println("Name: " + a.getName() + " Age: " + a.getAge());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `Info a = new Info();` is limited to the method that you have declared it in. Consider making it a field.

```
public class Test {

    private Info a = new Info();

    Test test = new Test();
    test.method1();
    test.method2();
}

  public void method1() {
    a.setName("John");
    a.setAge(21);
  }

  public void method2() {
    System.out.println("Name: "+ a.getName() + " Age: " + a.getAge());
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could create local variables, but pass them between the methods:

In main

```
 Info a = new Info();
 Test test = new Test();
 test.method1(a);
 test.method2(a);
```

Of course this would require you change you method signatures to

```
public void method1(Info a) {...}
public void method2(Info a) {...}
```

Comment: If it helps please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

A private global variable can only be set by a method that is private.

A method that is private can only be called inside the class it is coded(implemented).
However, inside the class you can mix security declarations levels of variables in code, but to set or get the method used must be as the variable it sets or gets with or without a method return statement.

To set and obtain(get) anything private from calls located outside the class **you must use a public method inside the same class to call the private methods** or if the calling class is in the same (class package hierarchy) packages hierarchy level and package tree you can use a protected method to call from such an external class but that in the external class must be called by a protected method (potentially)returning to a protected variable.

If there is only the default level "no access security declaration of the class" given (e.g. public protected - nothing stated but "class NamedAClass"), of such a class with the get set then it is similar but more lax security than private using default security level, with default security level , you can only call from a class located in the exact same package as the class with the code to call.